# Filter unique data in Django

Tags: python, django, filter

*Since Im been using mysql, I found some answer but it conflicts to my other filtering data WHEN I PLACED RETURN RENDER OUTSIDE THE LOOP it only returns single value but when I placed return render inside my loop it works fine but the problem is I have another person variable, if I place this inside the the loop it keeps looping my person variable.

[image]

> Expected output should like this, and to filter this data to my select option

```
China
Denver
Manila
Tokyo
Japan
Usa
Australia
Brazil
```

> views.py

```
 def sample(request):
    staff = Person.objects.all().values('classification').distinct()
    for k in staff:
        j = k['classification']
    person= Person.objects.all()
    formats = {'data1':person, 'classification':j}
    return render (request,'sample.html',formats)
```

Is there any expert know about this?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to django docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

All you need to do is add a  .distinct() to the queryset

Comment: thanks for your response , I added some code above and I used mysql but do you have idea about my added question above?

Comment: Though you have added the distinct, you are not using the variable staff which contains the result, you are using a different variable 'person'. Correct this one

Comment: Im been using  `formats = {'data1':person, 'classification':j} ` to fetch the data, the J variable is equivalent to staff but since I didn't put J variable inside loop it only return one value . The person you mention  it is only another query filter it conflicts when I put all my data and return inside the loop, though the distinct result is work the remaining value keeps repeating since it is inside the loop , do you have idea regarding with this problem? Im just stuck with this module :/

Answer (score 0):

Check out `set`, converting your list of data to a Set should remove duplicates.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Comment: thanks for your response , I added some code above and I used mysql but do you have idea about my added question above?